# check if a linear operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

> show that $Tf = f(0)$ is not a bounded linear functional on the space of continuous functions measured with the L2 norm, but it is a bounded linear functional if measured using the uniform norm.

Attempt:
for the linear operator to be bounded, we need to show that $\frac{||Tf||}{||f||}\leq c <\infty$. 
but i really don't understand my space. the question says continuous function with L2 norm. but this is not a normed space since not all continuous functions are square integrable. so is my objects in this space square integrable continuous functions ?

Comment: Yes, your first space consists of the continuous functions that are square integrable.

Comment: What is the domain of the continuous functions? Probably, the space in question is $C(I)$, where $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact interval containing $0$, and then all continuous functions on $I$ are square integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $C[0,1]$ you can put

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}-n^2x+n,&0\leq x\leq 1/n\\0,&1/n\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$

Then $\|f_n\|_2=\sqrt{n/3}$ and $|T(f_n)|/\|f_n\|_2=n/\sqrt{n/3}\to\infty$.

---

On the other hand, $|T(f)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: Why did you take a sequence? @Alamos Even the book says: "Find a sequence of functions whose L2 norm is uniformly bounded but whose value at zero is unbounded". I don't understand how sequences came into the picture.